# Can I stop UWP app from being dragged beyond its bounds when keyboard is shown?

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have an application using `Xamarin.Forms` Running on `UWP`

When the keyboard is visible I am able to drag the application around to see the rest of the screen. But I can also drag it beyond its bounds, which shows a black background. See screenshot below:
[image]
Is it possible to change the colour of this background or stop the application from dragging beyond its bounds when the keyboard is visible? As this behavior is confusing to my users

Comment: Is the view content able to drag when the keyboard does not appear?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT No the view is a `Xamarin.Forms` ContentPage The "Previous Call Notes" May possibly be a `ScrollView`

Comment: If the `ScrollView` had been set [`CanDrag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/drag-and-drop) by using XAML like `<ScrollViewer CanDrag="True"></ScrollViewer>`, and the the scrollView will be draggable. You could set `CanDrag="False"`to prevent dragging.

Comment: Thanks @NicoZhu-MSFT I will look into that. Is There any way I can change the Background Colour from Black to something else?